# Filter an html table into another table by a value and removing columns with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have two html tables id="source" and id="destination"

the source table has 7 columns and the destination table has 5 columns.

I need to filter the data by col2(value 150) into the destination table, but only display columns 1, 3, 4, 5 and 6. In another words ignore col2 and col7 as the image shows.
[image]
I've seen some examples of that, but they are all in jquery and I would like to do this with javascript as I'm not familiar with jquery.
I was using two functions and still not getting the results I need.

```
function copytable() {
var source = document.getElementById('source');
var destination = document.getElementById('destination');
var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
copy.setAttribute('id', 'destination');
destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);
filterTable();
}

function filterTable() {
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("destination");
 tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
if (td) {
  if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";
  } else {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}       
}
}
```

Comment: Please also add code you have tried so far

Comment: I added my poor code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is step by step, all explanations are described in `javascript` code :

```js
function filterValue() {
 var vl = document.getElementById('txtValue').value; //get value for filtering
 var stbl = document.getElementById('source');  //get source table
 var dtbl = document.getElementById('destionation'); //get destination table
 for(var i=0;i<stbl.rows.length;i++) {  //loop through source table
   var row=stbl.rows[i]; //get row (one by one) from source table
   if(row.cells[1].innerHTML==vl) {  //if entered value is equal with value into col2 of source table
    var newrow=dtbl.insertRow();  //create new row in destination table
    for(var x=0;x<row.cells.length;x++) { //loop through all cells
      if(x!=1 && x!=6) {  //take, "copy", all cells expect col2 and col7 cells
        var cell=newrow.insertCell(); //add cell in new created row
        cell.innerHTML=row.cells[x].innerHTML; //"copy" value from source cell into destination cell
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

```css
#source, #destionation {margin-top:15px; border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;}
#source tr:first-child, #destionation tr:first-child {background-color:#B6D7A8; border-bottom:solid 1px #c0c0c0;}
```

```html
Filter by value from <b>col2</b> : 
<input type="text" id="txtValue" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Filter" onclick="filterValue();" /><br>
  <table id="source" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td>col1</td>
  <td>col2</td>
  <td>col3</td>
  <td>col4</td>
  <td>col5</td>
  <td>col6</td>
  <td>col7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>45</td><td>150</td><td>john</td><td>3.00</td><td>15.00</td><td>95</td><td>45:00:00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>46</td><td>150</td><td>Anyone</td><td>3.00</td><td>15.00</td><td>95</td><td>37:00:00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>49</td><td>220</td><td>Not included</td><td>3.00</td><td>15.00</td><td>95</td><td>15:22:00</td></tr>
 <tr><td>48</td><td>150</td><td>And so on</td><td>3.00</td><td>15.00</td><td>95</td><td>35:50:00</td></tr>
 </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="destionation" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td>col1</td>
  <td>col3</td>
  <td>col4</td>
  <td>col5</td>
  <td>col6</td>
 </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect, it works. I should have provided some of the code so you wouldn't have to do the HTML and CSS from scratch. I'm also greatful for the comment lines on the script.Thanks a lot!